# Maven dependencies in external jar files not loading

Tags: java, maven, jar, sdk

I'm having a spring based project which does not have any build management tools like maven/gradle. For dependencies I'm adding the jar files to the build path. Some dependencies like aws-java-sdk and others having only pom.xml files in their jar files. These additional dependencies for the jar files are not getting downloaded from maven central repo. Is there any additional configuration need to be done for this?

Comment: I would start using Maven or Gradle.

Comment: @JFabianMeier will the external jar files download their required dependencies only if we use build tools for our project? or is there any other configuration that needs to be done?

Comment: You have to define the dependencies you use in your pom.xml (Maven) or gralde.build for Gradle.... I strongly recommend to start using a build tool... it helps a lot...

Answer (score 0):

For dependency resolution, you need a build tool.

The standard tools nowadays are Maven or Gradle.